Installing an Ecobee 3 Lite PEK to my air conditioner with NO control board
I'm trying to install an Ecobee 3 Lite and upgrade the old thermostat.  It's setup as air conditioning only. I do not have a C wire, only R, Y, and G so I need to install the PEK at the air conditioner unit.  Unfortunately, my air conditioner does not have a control board and I am having a difficult time finding where the wires leading to the thermostat are.  I think I have located them but I'm only seeing the red and white, and the green wire is nowhere to be found.  No idea where to install the PEK.  I'd like to do this myself but I may have to call an HVAC or electrician soon if I can't figure it out.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.  I have pics I will try to upload if that helps.

Can you post photos of your air handler's wiring, as well as the wiring diagram for your air handler please?

Sure.  I need to find out how to attach photos here.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/ww9P4q2Vni9Byc448

https://photos.app.goo.gl/HNPs6tGzxPMb7cR68

https://photos.app.goo.gl/CfEiSGV8DDuLEQDo6

we need to see the wiring for your indoor unit (air handler) not your outdoor unit (condensing unit)
